# How Sonarqube understands branch coverage

Tags: c++, sonarqube, code-coverage

My question regards strange (to me) code coverage reports in SonarQube (sonar cloud).
Let's take this file: https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures?branch=develop&id=org.sonarqube%3Aaudio-tk&metric=coverage&selected=org.sonarqube%3Aaudio-tk%3AATK%2FDelay%2FFeedbackDelayNetworkFilter.hxx
It is very partially covered, but for instance the constructors are marked as partially covered, which makes no sense to me. Or l113, it says partially covered, but there is no condition, so why is it partially covered? Same for the for loop in the last method, as they are fully covered or l141 which is partially covered without reason (the test makes sure that the condition is false by default).

Comment: SonarQube only relays what the coverage reports you feed in say. You should re-cast this question to be about your coverage engine rather than about SonarQube/SonarCloud.

Comment: OK. So that means that I would also get coverage with llvm coverage and it could be different.
Unfortunately, the only example for llcm import seems to be for one library for one run, whereas in my case I have lots of tests with lots of libraries to check. How can sonarqube understand that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that for branches, the templates instantiations are also used. So what I have to do is to create test cases for all these different types, and not just double.